# how to solve the pytorch_geometric install error. Undefined symbol: _ZN5torch3jit17parseSchemaOrNameERKSs #999

Tags: pytorch

how to solve the pytorch_geometric install error. Undefined symbol: _ZN5torch3jit17parseSchemaOrNameERKSs #999

solution:
conda install pytorch pyg -c pytorch -c pyg -c conda-forge

conda create -n py38 pip

conda install pytorch pyg -c pytorch -c pyg -c conda-forge

conda install pyg -c pyg -c conda-forge

sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev

pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: conda create -n py38 pip
conda install pytorch pyg -c pytorch -c pyg -c conda-forge
conda install pyg -c pyg -c conda-forge
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
pip install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. As mentioned in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/issues/999#issuecomment-593482341), this issue occurs when we have different torch versions installed in our system. This problem occurred in my anaconda virtual environment, which I installed in the following path.

```
/home/anaconda3/envs/python-3.9
```

I followed the following steps to solve this issue.

**Step 01**: First remove all the existing torch installations and their dependencies.

```
$ cd /home/anaconda3/envs/python-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
$ rm -rf torch*
```

**Step 02**: Reinstall a specific PyTorch version and relevant dependencies as follows.

```
$ pip install torch -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-<PYTORCH-VERSION>+<CPU|GPU>.html
$ pip install torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-<PYTORCH-VERSION>+<CPU|GPU>.html
$ pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-<<PYTORCH-VERSION>+<CPU|GPU>.html
$ pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-<PYTORCH-VERSION>+<CPU|GPU>.html
```

Make sure you install a PyTorch version according to your requirements and your system (CPU or GPU). For example, I installed the following version.

```
$ pip install torch -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.12.1+cpu.html
$ pip install torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.12.1+cpu.html
$ pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.12.1+cpu.html
$ pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.12.1+cpu.html
```

You can find all the [stable PyTorch versions here](https://data.pyg.org/whl/). In addition, now you will be able to see the installed packages inside your anaconda installation path `/home/anaconda3/envs/python-3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.

Comment: Did not work for me, pip just installed the latest version and was ignoring the url

Comment: This was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192037/could-not-import-torch-geometric-it-says-undefined-symbol-zn5torch3jit17pars/75307617#75307617
You can easily check what are the versions and where is the mismatch this way:

`python -c "import torch; print(torch.version.cuda); import torch; print(torch.__version__); import torch_geometric; print(torch_geometric.__version__)"`

`nvcc --version`

The important thing being the `torch.version.cuda` vs the nvcc one.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me!

TL,DR;
At first, I tried to install pytorch from pytorch official site but, it didn't work. I have to install all of the torch-related packages from `https://data.pyg.org/whl.index.html`. In my case, I have to install `torch-2.0.1+cu118` but the terminal printed `Downloading torch-2.2.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (755.5 MB)`.
Anyway, `torch-2.0.1+cu118` was installed and, I continued to install the rest of the packages which are `geometric`, `sparse`, `scatter`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check here:
https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/issues/999

Most people say it is due to how you installed pytorch and two versions (the cpu and gpu versions are both installed)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I have installed pytorch using conda and pip so I just deleted the packages installed by pip and it worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).