# Could not import torch_geometric, it says "undefined symbol: _ZN5torch3jit17parseSchemaOrNameERKSs"

Tags: kaggle, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I am trying to find a solution to the error:
**OSError: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_sparse/_version_cuda.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5torch3jit17parseSchemaOrNameERKSs**.

arising from the statement `from torch_geometric.data import Data` in Kaggle notebook.

There are solutions in [github](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/issues/999) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69952475/how-to-solve-the-pytorch-geometric-install-error-undefined-symbol-zn5torch3ji), but none are working.

-- "nvcc --version" shows

"nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:09_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0"

I tried to install torch-geometric by

1. !conda install pyg -c pyg -c conda-forge
2. !pip install pyg-lib torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster torch-spline-conv torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.12.0+cu113.html

from [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/installation.html).

The first statement took more than 1 hour so I moved to the second, which installed it. But the error didn't go.

**It is running with out any error in colab.**

Answer (score 2):

This issue is mentionned at  https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html :

> undefined symbol: **make_function_schema**: This issue signals (1) a version conflict
> between your installed PyTorch version and the ${TORCH} version
> specified to install the extension packages, or (2) a version conflict
> between the installed CUDA version of PyTorch and the ${CUDA} version
> specified to install the extension packages. Please verify that your
> PyTorch version and its CUDA version match with your installation
> command:

```
python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
python -c "import torch; print(torch.version.cuda)"
nvcc --version
```

> For re-installation, ensure that you do not run into any caching issues by
> using the pip --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir flags. In addition, the
> pip --verbose option may help to track down any issues during
> installation. If you still do not find any success in installation,
> please try to install the extension packages from source.

So, I would try these commands, and re-install all or part of the packages into a fresh environment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there could be various specific culprits to this, but in my case it was simply missing `torchtext`. Make sure you have that installed and the version is compatible.